# Group data based on case statements in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of data and I would want to group 2 columns based on a logic formed from a few case statements in a new column. This is my data:

[image]

And this is my current sql:

```
select a.Action,st.State,ym.Year,sum(RatingCount) as LevelCount
from ActionTable a
left join StateTable st on a.ID = st.ActionID
left join YearMetrics ym a.Name = ym.NameCategory and st.Name = ym.CategoryName
group by a.name,st.name,ym.Year,ym.Level
```

These are the case statements (not all of them) base on which the logic should apply:

```
case when level = 'high' and levelcount >= 1 then 'High'
case when level = 'medium' and levelcount >3 then 'High'
else Low
end as Level
```

So, for example in case of Oregon (lines 20,21,22) I would want, based on the case statements to group the data on Action, State, Year. A new column named Level should be formed based from the logic on the case statements. So in the case of line 20, because there is no case statements to match the data in the table the result should be:

```
Non-Travel Oregon 2020 Low
```

The lines 21,22 should be:

```
Non-Travel Oregon 2021 High
```

because, according to the case statements, there is one levelcount >=1 and Level is High. In the case of line 19 the result should be :

```
Non-Travel Nevada null null
```

What I have tried includes:

- Partitions
- CLR object to include the logic in a c# assembly
- Stuff function
- Group by case statements

I have not managed to obtain the desired result using any of the techniques.

This is the expected result:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Comment: You show NULL results for some states, yet you outer join to your state table. Same thing for year. Presumably you need to cross join all years against all states as a start. Perhaps you also want all categories - in which case you will need to cross join that "list" as well. Then you join to the aggregated data. No idea where "Level" comes from.

Comment: `case` *expression* (not statement) and please don't use images for data, use formatted text.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be the logic that you are describing:

```
select a.Action, st.State, ym.Year,
       sum(RatingCount) as LevelCount,
       (case when level = 'high' and sum(RatingCount) >= 1 then 'High'
             when level = 'medium' and sum(RatingCount) > 3 then 'High'
             when level = 'medium' then 'Low'
        end) as Level
from ActionTable a left join
     StateTable st
     on a.ID = st.ActionID left join
     YearMetrics ym
     on a.Name = ym.NameCategory and st.Name = ym.CategoryName
group by a.name, st.name, ym.Year, ym.Level;
```

Comment: I have edited my Question, and added the expected results, sorry for bad formatting.

Comment: @Daniel . . . I think this does what you want.

Comment: I have tried this previously. The issue is that data is grouped by ym.level, which results in not grouping the table by Action, State and Year fully. I mean data is grouped by these 3 columns but also by ym.level which I do not want. When I eliminate ym.Level, the issue which arise is that 'level' from the case statements is not contained in a group by clause or a an aggregate function. So basically, this is my issue: how I aggregate level column by those case statements.

Comment: Does replacing `ym.Level` in the `group by` with the big `case` statement not work?

Comment: @SteveLovell . . . (1) That will not work.  (2) Your specified results are inconsistent with the explanation, because Oregon is repeated in the explanation, but not the results.  (3) You can set up a db fiddle of some sort to illustrate the data.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't noticed the aggregation within the `case`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the stated expected results are not compatible with what you've give us in terms of rules of how to derive them. It also doesn't help that your data rather than being the raw data is the output of your existing query. As a result, it feels like we're guessing a bit here ...

The query I've given below doesn't return what you say you want, but it's close and I think agrees with your explanation.

```
WITH subquery AS
(
  select a.Action,st.State,ym.Year,ym.Level,sum(RatingCount) as LevelCount
  from ActionTable a
  left join StateTable st on a.ID = st.ActionID
  left join YearMetrics ym a.Name = ym.NameCategory and st.Name = ym.CategoryName
  group by a.name,st.name,ym.Year,ym.Level
) --This is just your original code with ym.Level added to the SELECT clause.

SELECT
  s.Action,
  s.State,
  s.Year,
  CASE WHEN s.Level = 'high'   AND s.LevelCount >=1 THEN 'High'
       WHEN s.Level = 'medium' AND s.LevelCount  >0 THEN 'High'
       WHEN s.Level IS NULL THEN NULL --If you don't do this, NULLs become 'Low'
       ELSE 'Low'
  END AS NewLevel
FROM
  subquery s
GROUP BY
  s.Action,
  s.State,
  s.Year,
  CASE WHEN s.Level = 'high'   AND s.LevelCount >=1 THEN 'High'
       WHEN s.Level = 'medium' AND s.LevelCount  >0 THEN 'High'
       WHEN s.Level IS NULL THEN NULL
       ELSE 'Low'
  END
```